# Input with Javascript code plus and minus I need to fire event change on plus and minus

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have input with JavaScript code plus and minus, I need to fire event change on plus and minus click because I call ajax to update cart with the new quantity.

This code doesn't work : `currentInput.change;`.
You will find that row in Javascript file, so we need to correct it, I can not copyright CSS,
if you can correct it on your side.

Here I don't know what I need to make it work here but it works fine with me minus and plus.

This is my JavaScript file:

```js
    (function ($) {
  $.fn.niceNumber = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      autoSize: true,
      autoSizeBuffer: 1,
      buttonDecrement: '-',
      buttonIncrement: "+",
      buttonPosition: 'around'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function(){
      var currentInput = this,
          $currentInput = $(currentInput),
          attrMax = null,
          attrMin = null;

      // Handle max and min values
      if (
        typeof $currentInput.attr('max') !== typeof undefined
        && $currentInput.attr('max') !== false
      ) {
        attrMax = parseFloat($currentInput.attr('max'));
      }

      if (
        typeof $currentInput.attr('min') !== typeof undefined
        && $currentInput.attr('min') !== false
      ) {
        attrMin = parseFloat($currentInput.attr('min'));
      }

      // Fix issue with initial value being < min
      if (
        attrMin
        && !currentInput.value
      ) {
        $currentInput.val(attrMin);
      }

      // Generate container
      var $inputContainer = $('<div/>',{
          class: 'nice-number'
        })
        .insertAfter(currentInput);

      // Generate interval (object so it is passed by reference)
      var interval = {};

      // Generate buttons
      var $minusButton = $('<button/>')
        .attr('type', 'button').attr('class', 'minus_btn')
        .html(settings.buttonDecrement)
        .on('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', function(event){
          changeInterval(event.type, interval, function(){
            if (
              attrMin == null
              || attrMin < parseFloat(currentInput.value)
            ) {
              currentInput.value--;
                currentInput.change;
            }
          });

          // Trigger the input event here to avoid event spam
          if (
            event.type == 'mouseup'
            || event.type == 'mouseleave'
          ) {
            $currentInput.trigger('input');
          }
        });

      var $plusButton = $('<button/>')
        .attr('type', 'button').attr('class', 'plus_btn')
        .html(settings.buttonIncrement)
        .on('mousedown mouseup mouseleave', function(event){
            changeInterval(event.type, interval, function(){
                if (
                    attrMax == null
                    || attrMax > parseFloat(currentInput.value)
                ) {
                    currentInput.value++;
                    currentInput.change;
                }
            });

          // Trigger the input event here to avoid event spam
          if (
            event.type == 'mouseup'
            || event.type == 'mouseleave'
          ) {
            $currentInput.trigger('input');
          }
        });

      // Append elements
      switch (settings.buttonPosition) {
        case 'left':
          $minusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $plusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $currentInput.appendTo($inputContainer);
          break;
        case 'right':
          $currentInput.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $minusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $plusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          break;
        case 'around':
        default:
          $minusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $currentInput.appendTo($inputContainer);
          $plusButton.appendTo($inputContainer);
          break;
      }

      // Nicely size input
      if (settings.autoSize) {
        $currentInput.width(
          $currentInput.val().length+settings.autoSizeBuffer+"ch"
        );
        $currentInput.on('keyup input',function(){
          $currentInput.animate({
            'width': $currentInput.val().length+settings.autoSizeBuffer+"ch"
          }, 200);
        });
      }
    });
  };

  function changeInterval(eventType, interval, callback) {
    if (eventType == "mousedown") {
      interval.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        interval.actualInterval = setInterval(function(){
          callback();
        }, 100);
      }, 200);
      callback();
    } else {
      if (interval.timeout) {
        clearTimeout(interval.timeout);
      }
      if (interval.actualInterval) {
        clearInterval(interval.actualInterval);
      }
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
            $(function(){

                $('input[type="number"]').niceNumber();

            });
        </script>
<div class="number_pluse fashion_number">
                                        <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="{{ $product->product_qty}}" name="quantity">
                                    </div>
```

Comment: You need to invoke the change method with `()` .... `currentInput.change()`. I don't see where you have any `on('change', func)` though

Comment: `currentInput.change` -> `currentInput.change()` or `currentInput.trigger("change")` as you do for `input` - or raise a *new* event namespaced to your application/plugin (see namespaced events)

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: it doesn't work